# Why am I receiving an "Undefined constant" error?

Tags: constants, undefined

Apache 2.4 / PHP 8.3.1 / MySQL 8.0 / phpMyAdmin 5.2.1.

I believe the code may be outdated for the upgrades and my coding ability is not that great.

The above programs are working together.  Meaning Apache is providing the server function, PHP is parsing, MySQL & phpMyAdmin are reflecting the same information....

However, I keep getting the following message upon submitting a simple form:

The input is the following from a HTML code fps_show_adduser.php:

```
<P><STRONG>First Name:</STRONG><BR>
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="f_name" SIZE=45 MAXLENGTH=45></p>
```

SUBMIT is the following:

```
<P><INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" NAME="submit" VALUE="Add User"></P>
</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

The error is the below:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "f_name" in C:\Apache24\htdocs\fps_do_adduser.php:3 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\Apache24\htdocs\fps_do_adduser.php on line 3

The code for the input is using `<FORM METHOD="POST" ACTION="fps_do_adduser.php">`.

The submit portion is working, but I get the above error.  This same code works for PHP 5.6.26.  Apache 2.4.23.

I have tried a `var_dump($_POST[f_name])` and no information other than an error.

The "constant" is something I am not familiar with as this "INPUT" acts as a variable from the user.

```
<P><STRONG>First Name:</STRONG><BR>
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="f_name" SIZE=45 MAXLENGTH=45></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

FORGET this ladies & gentlemen.

The issue was placing quotes around the "$_POST[f_name]".  The VAR_DUMP may not be correct to whoever reads this.  However, using the $_POST[f_name] was not correct.  This needed to be changed to "$_POST[f_name]".

Thank you to anyone who took the time to help....M